# Is there a way to make the ApplicationMaster in YARN to act as a CONTAINER for a single container job?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I have a custom MR Scoop job with DBInputSplit which is map only job and has a parallelism configured so that it calculates the split and launches those number of mappers, however if I don't give any parallelism I don't want the AppMaster in YARN to launch another container and manage instead I would like to utilise the AppMaster as a container itself as the DB Connection is single threaded from mapper. Is there any property available to enable this?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by enabling Uber mode i.e   `mapreduce.job.ubertask.enable=true`

more details [here](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.1.15/bk_using-apache-hadoop/content/uber_jobs.html)